# azure cognitive service synapse sentiment

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-cognitive-services

I have the following code

```
from synapse.ml.cognitive import *

input_df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("I am so happy today, its sunny!", "en-US"),
  ("I am frustrated by this rush hour traffic", "en-US"),
  ("The cognitive services on spark aint bad", "en-US"),
], ["text", "language"])

sentiment_df = (TextSentiment()
    .setTextCol("text")
    .setLocation("eastus")
    .setUrl(end_point)
    .setSubscriptionKey(service_key)
    .setOutputCol("sentiment")
    .setErrorCol("error")
    .setLanguageCol("language")
    .transform(input_df))
```

I created azure cognititve text service and used the same endpoint and key

but when running the code getting the following error, Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import synapse.ml 

from synapse.ml.cognitive import * 

from pyspark.sql.functions import col 

input_df = spark.createDataFrame([ 

  ("I am so happy today, its sunny!", "en-US"), 

  ("I am frustrated by this rush hour traffic", "en-US"), 

  ("The cognitive services on spark aint bad", "en-US"), 

], ["text", "language"]) 

 

Sentiment_df = (TextSentiment() 

    .setLinkedService(linked_service_name) 

    .setTextCol("text") 

    .setLocation("eastus") 

    .setUrl(end_point) 

    .setSubscriptionKey(service_key) 

    .setOutputCol("sentiment") 

    .setErrorCol("error") 

    .setLanguageCol("language") 

 

display(sentiment.transform(df).select("text", col("sentiment")[0].getItem("sentiment").alias("sentiment"), col(“service_key”)[1].getItem(“service_key”).alias(“service_key”), col(“language”)[2].getItem(“language”).alias(“language”) 

))
```

The error occurred due to the pattern of calling the display method. Replace the code block below with the above-mentioned code block.

```
from synapse.ml.cognitive import * 

 

input_df = spark.createDataFrame([ 

  ("I am so happy today, its sunny!", "en-US"), 

  ("I am frustrated by this rush hour traffic", "en-US"), 

  ("The cognitive services on spark aint bad", "en-US"), 

], ["text", "language"]) 

 

sentiment_df = (TextSentiment() 

    .setTextCol("text") 

    .setLocation("eastus") 

    .setUrl(end_point) 

    .setSubscriptionKey(service_key) 

    .setOutputCol("sentiment") 

    .setErrorCol("error") 

    .setLanguageCol("language") 

    .transform(input_df))
```

The expected answer will be like below.

[image]

Comment: what is linked_service_name here ?

Comment: linked_service_name is **KEY_VAULT_LINKED_SERVICE_NAME. **

Comment: I didn't use any key vault service , is that mandatory ?

Comment: It is not mandatory. You can use remaining part by excluding that as you are not using it.

Comment: Its not useful. getting the same error after the changes.